# What is the best way to refactor generators pipeline as coroutines?

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

Consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from string import letters


def filter_upper(letters):
    for letter in letters:
        if letter.isupper():
            yield letter

def filter_selected(letters, selected):
    selected = set(map(str.lower, selected))
    for letter in letters:
        if letter.lower() in selected:
            yield letter


def main():
    stuff = filter_selected(filter_upper(letters), ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    print(list(stuff))

main()
```

This is the illustration of a pipeline constructed from generators. I often use this pattern in practice to build data processing flow. It's like UNIX pipes.

What is the most elegant way to refactor the generators to coroutines that suspend execution every `yield`?

### UPDATE

My first try was like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def coro():
    for e in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        future = asyncio.Future()
        future.set_result(e)
        yield from future


@asyncio.coroutine
def coro2():
    a = yield from coro()
    print(a)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(coro2())
```

But for some reason it doesnt work - variable `a` becomes `None`.

### UPDATE #1

What I came up with recently:

**Server:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
"""Server that accepts a client and send it strings from user input."""


import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
port = 5555

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

print('Listening...')

conn, addr = s.accept()

print('Client ({}) connected.'.format(addr))

while True:
    conn.send(raw_input('Enter data to send: '))
```

**Client:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
"""Client that demonstrates processing pipeline."""

import trollius as asyncio
from trollius import From


@asyncio.coroutine
def upper(input, output):
    while True:
        char = yield From(input.get())
        print('Got char: ', char)
        yield From(output.put(char.upper()))


@asyncio.coroutine
def glue(input, output):
    chunk = []
    while True:
        e = yield From(input.get())
        chunk.append(e)
        print('Current chunk: ', chunk)
        if len(chunk) == 3:
            yield From(output.put(chunk))
            chunk = []


@asyncio.coroutine
def tcp_echo_client(loop):
    reader, writer = yield From(asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 5555,
                                                        loop=loop))
    q1 = asyncio.Queue()
    q2 = asyncio.Queue()
    q3 = asyncio.Queue()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def printer():
        while True:
            print('Pipeline ouput: ', (yield From(q3.get())))

    asyncio.async(upper(q1, q2))
    asyncio.async(glue(q2, q3))
    asyncio.async(printer())

    while True:
        data = yield From(reader.read(100))
        print('Data: ', data)

        for byte in data:
            yield From(q1.put(byte))

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()


@asyncio.coroutine
def background_stuff():
    while True:
        yield From(asyncio.sleep(3))
        print('Other background stuff...')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.async(background_stuff())
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(loop))
loop.close()
```

Advantage over ["David Beazley's coroutines"](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) is that you can use all `asyncio` stuff inside such processing units with `input` and `output` queues.
Disadvantage here - a lot of queues instances needed for connecting pipeline units. It can be fixed with use of data sructure more advanced than `asyncio.Queue`.
Another disadvantage is that such kind of processing units does not propagate their exceptions to a parent stack frame, because they are "background tasks", whereas "David Beazley's coroutines" does propagate.

### UPDATE #2

That's with what I came up:
https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/04c287def6d165fc2832

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer here is "you don't". I'm guessing that you're getting this idea from David Beazley's [famous coroutine/generator tutorial](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf). In his tutorials, he's using coroutines as basically a reversed generator pipeline. Instead of pulling the data through the pipeline by iterating over generators, you push data through the pipeline using `gen_object.send()`. Your first example would look something like this using this notion of coroutines:

```
from string import letters

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        cr = func(*args,**kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start

@coroutine
def filter_upper(target):
    while True:
        letter = yield
        if letter.isupper():
            target.send(letter)

@coroutine
def filter_selected(selected):
    selected = set(map(str.lower, selected))
    out = []
    try:
        while True:
            letter = yield
            if letter.lower() in selected:
                out.append(letter)
    except GeneratorExit:
        print out

def main():
    filt = filter_upper(filter_selected(['a', 'b', 'c']))
    for letter in letters:
        filt.send(letter)
    filt.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, the coroutines in `asyncio` are similar in that they're suspendable generator objects which can have data sent into them, but they really aren't meant for the data pipelining use-case at all. They're meant to be used to enable concurrency when you're executing blocking I/O operations. The `yield from` suspension points allow control to return to the event loop while the I/O happens, and the event loop will restart the coroutine when it completes, sending the data returned by the I/O call into the coroutine. There's really no practical reason to try to use them for this kind of use case, since there's no blocking I/O happening at all.

Also, the problem with your attempt at using `asyncio` is that `a = yield from coro()` is assigning a to the *return value* of `coro`. But you're not actually returning anything from `coro`. You're caught somewhere between treating `coro` as an actual coroutine and a generator. It looks like you're expecting `yield from future` to send the contents of `future` from `coro` to `coro2`, but that's not how coroutines work. `yield from` is used to pull data from a coroutine/`Future`/`Task`, and `return` is used to actually send an object back to the caller. So, for `coro` to actually return something to `coro2`, you need to do this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def coro():
    for e in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        future = asyncio.Future()
        future.set_result(e)
        return future
```

But that's just going to end with `'a'` being returned to `coro2`. I think to get the output you expect you'd need to do this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def coro():
    future = asyncio.Future()
    future.set_result(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    return future
```

Which maybe demonstrates why `asyncio` coroutines are not what you want here.

**Edit:**

Ok, given a case where you want to use pipelining in addition to actually making use of async I/O, I think the approach you used in your update is good. As you suggested, it can be made simpler by creating a data structure to help automate the queue management:

```
class Pipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, *nodes):
        if len(nodes) < 2:
            raise Exception("Need at least two nodes in the pipeline")
        self.start = asyncio.Queue()
        in_ = self.start
        for node in nodes:
            out = asyncio.Queue()
            asyncio.async(node(in_, out))
            in_ = out

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def put(self, val):
        yield from self.start.put(val)

# ... (most code is unchanged)

@asyncio.coroutine
def printer(input_, output): 
    # For simplicity, I have the sink taking an output queue. Its not being used,
    # but you could make the final output queue accessible from the Pipeline object
    # and then add a get() method to the `Pipeline` itself.
    while True:
        print('Pipeline ouput: ', (yield from input_.get()))


@asyncio.coroutine
def tcp_echo_client(loop):
    reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 5555,
                                                        loop=loop)
    pipe = Pipeline(upper, glue, printer)

    while True:
        data = yield from reader.read(100)
        if not data:
            break
        print('Data: ', data)

        for byte in data.decode('utf-8'):
            yield from pipe.put(byte)  # Add to the pipe

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()
```

This simplifies `Queue` management, but doesn't address the exception handling issue. I'm not sure if much can be done about that...

Comment: The problem here is if I have asynchronous I/O with coroutines and more or less resource heavy processing pipeline - it becomes a bottleneck. And I'm thinking about how to elegantly introduce context switching into such pipelines.

Comment: @GillBates When you say resource heavy processing, are you talking about CPU resources?

Comment: The point is that a pipeline can block execution for some relatively big amount of time. So it is negates advantages of asynchronous IO - even if we dont wait for data from socket, we wait until its processed.

Comment: @GillBates I think your updated code is the (or at least a) right way to use pipelining within the `asyncio` framework. I added an edit that takes it a step further, introducing a `Pipeline` object to automate the `Queue` management.

Comment: Next question is how to elegantly propagate exceptions from pipeline.

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/04c287def6d165fc2832 Forks are appreciated.

Comment: @GillBates I actually wrote something very similar to that, except I decorated each `unit` in the pipeline to catch any thrown exception, and then added the exception/traceback to `self.output` in the decorator, instead of leveraging `asyncio.gather` and `asyncio.Future`. I think your way is nicer. I'll take a closer look at it when I have some free time and see if I can think of any improvements.